# how create id for webview android and get the id with php

Tags: php, android

How create id for webview android and get the id from webview with php, I just want to show my mobile web only for android webview that I created. with get the id from webview. i can detected the mobile device using php `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];`
but how if with id, can this be? and how to create the id and how get the id using php?

thanks

Comment: To show your web content only on your webview you can create your very own taylor made User Agent, something like `riskymaker`, for example, then detect it the way you know.

Comment: @statosdotcom, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the answer, with custome user agent in android webview.

for how custome the user agent, i see from this:
https://www.scientiamobile.com/page/correctly-form-user-agents-for-webview-apps

and how to detected the same character or id from user agent with php i use this code,.

```
<?php
//for real;
//$str = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

//for example
$str="Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A525 WebViewApp Foo/1 iPhone4,1";


$detect = "";

foreach (preg_split('/\s+/', $str) as $word)
{
  $word = strtolower($word);
    if($word == "webviewapp"){
        $detect .= "true";
    }else{
        $detect .= "";
    }
}

if($detect == true){
    echo "you can see me";
}else{
    echo "sorry forbidden..";
}
exit;
```

thanks..

Comment: I missed these reputation points (I could elaborate a nice and complete answer - remember: reputation is our "salary" here... the motivation for us to work in benefit of others)... Well... glad it worked. Good luck. Give plus one then! ahah